# Как предотвратить создание пустой БД SQLite в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Пытаюсь работать с базой данных `SQLite` в `Python`. Пишу класс для этой цели. В конструкторе класса пишу такие строки:

```
def __init__(self, file_name='test.db'):
    self.conn = sqlite3.connect(file_name)
    self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
```

Эта БД должна именно **хранить** данные. Поэтому, если что-то случилось с файлом БД, то обязательно нужно эту ситуацию обнаружить и сообщить админу.

Однако, если метод `sqlite3.connect(file_name)` не может открыть файл БД, то он просто пересоздаёт **пустую** БД. Это очень нежелательное поведение.

Сколько я не читал документацию, нигде не говорится ни про какие коды завершения или `except-оны`. Как поймать такую ситуацию?

Я понимаю, что можно средствами ОС обнаружить отсутствие файла БД, но это совсем не то... А вдруг - он есть, но испорчен? Поэтому вопрос: как предотвратить поведение по умолчанию метода `сonnect` и обнаружить ошибку?

Comment: МОЖЕТ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ другую базу данных? А то говорят, что SQLite - и не БД вообще, а ее "симуляция"  текстовым файлом...

Comment: в модуле множество `DatabaseError`, если файл повреждён он выбрасывает `sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database` и ничего не перетирает... приведите пример вашего "что-то случилось с файлом"

Comment: @VasylKolomiets это полноценная файловая СУБД. Никаких текстовых файлов в ней нет - там нормальный бинарный файл с В-деревьями.

Answer (score 4):

Поскольку имя файла БД никаким образов не инкапсулировано в какой-нибудь хитрой строке подключения - совершенно нормально делать проверку на существование файла перед его открытием.

В случае же если файл существует, но поврежден и не может быть прочитан - никто его автоматически пересоздавать не будет, вместо этого будет исключение.

---

Также вместо проверки на существование файла можно попробовать использовать формат URI для имени БД:

```
sqlite3.connect('file:test.db?mode=rw', uri=True)
```

Как сказано [в документации](https://www.sqlite.org/uri.html), в режиме rw драйвер sqlite не пытается  создать новую базу данных. Это API существует с версии 3.4

Comment: *вместо этого будет исключение* - можете ткнуть меня носом, где это написано?

Comment: @Sergey вот тут перечислены исключения: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#exceptions  Как вы думаете, зачем они там были бы перечислены если бы никогда не кидались? :-)

Comment: Где **перечислены** исключения, я знаю. Я задал вопрос о том, где написано, что метод *connect* бросает исключения и в каких случаях.

Comment: **Как вы думаете** - я никогда не пытаюсь додумывать за автора пакета, как он там думал, когда писал этот пакет. Я просто хочу, что бы это было написано в доке. А не в моём воображении..

Comment: **а что еще он может делать** - я проделал такой незамысловатый эксперимент: взял файл БД (рабочий) и с помощью *hexedit* замазал пробелом символ 'Q' в сигнатуре файла (второй байт). И выяснилось, что метод *connect* не делает в данном случае НИЧЕГО! И это очень плохо, так как исключение выскочило во время выполнения *select* и догадаться разработчику о том, что не он дурак, а повреждён файл БД - очень тяжело!  Поэтому - давайте не будем ДОДУМЫВАТЬ за разработчика....

Comment: **пересоздание базы при повреждени** - я такого не говорил. Я сказал *не может открыть файл БД*.  Открыть файл !!!

Comment: @Sergey напомню, в вопросе вы спрашивали как отловить ситуацию когда sqlite **не может открыть файл**. Так вот, если sqlite не смогла открыть файл - будет исключение. Если исключения нет - значит, файл открылся.

Comment: @Sergey как проверять целостность БД в условиях замены случайных байтов шальными hexedit - совершенно другой вопрос.

Comment: **если sqlite не смогла открыть файл - будет исключение.** - с точностью до наоборот. Если не может ОТКРЫТЬ - пересоздаст. А если открыл, но файл битый - будет исключение в непредсказуемый момент.

Comment: @Sergey нет. sqlite не пересоздает те файлы которые не смогла открыть. Создаются (заметьте, не **пере**создаются!) только несуществующие файлы.

Comment: *Как сказано в документации* - Единственное, что я там нашёл: *The advantage of using a URI filename is that query parameters on the URI can be used to control details of the newly created database connection.* Т.е. можно управлять РЕЖИМАМИ создания файла. Но не самим фактом создания.

Comment: @Sergey читайте дальше. Там есть такой режим как `rwc`, который расшифровывается как *"read-write and created if it does not exist"* - именно это поведение вы и наблюдаете по умолчанию.

Comment: Да, похоже, это то, что надо. Попытаюсь проверить.

Comment: Вы оказались правы! Если написать так: *con = sqlite3.connect('file:/home/lary/projects/catalog.db?mode=rw', uri=True)* и убрать файл БД, то выбрасывается исключение *OperationalError* !

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю перед открытием файла, делать проверку на существование.

```
def __init__(self, file_name='test.db'):
    if os.path.isfile(file_name='test.db'):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(file_name)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
    else:
        raise FileExistsError(file_name)
```

Comment: Вариант, разумеется, не 100%, но хотя бы это придётся сделать.

Comment: Можно еще проверять, является ли файл БД. Вообще если файл не БД, при первом cur.execute должно вывалиться исключение